# How can I remove the fit bit icon off my menu bar on macOS?

Tags: macos, mac, menu-bar

I downloaded Fitbit onto my computer and then deleted  it (to the trash), but I can not get the icon to delete from my menu bar. I have tried to drag it over so it will delete, but it will not move.

Comment: Did you uninstall it using the FitBit uninstall application or did you just delete the icon?  I've seen where you need to [use the uninstaller application](https://community.fitbit.com/t5/Fitbit-com-Dashboard/Fit-bit-flex-icon-on-Mac-Book-menu-bar/m-p/342212) in order to remove the icon from the menu bar.

Answer (score 7):

If you have the Fitbit Connect installer software the Downloads folder on your computer, just run the Uninstall Fitbit Connect.app:

[image]

If you don't have the installer, [download a new version here](https://www.fitbit.com/setup?platform=mac), then run the Uninstall app.

It is also a good idea to reboot after the uninstall process completes.